# How do I interpret this Python Array code?

Tags: python, numpy

So I am teaching myself Python and I recently stumbled upon these kinds of code:
`plt.scatter(X_pca_2c[:,0], X_pca_2c[:,1], c=iris.target,
alpha=0.8, edgecolors='none')` 
and `np.array(tf_vect.get_feature_names())[tsvd_2c.components_[20].argsort
()[-10:][::-1]]`

The functions are too advanced for me at this stage, I know, but I am learning Python arrays now and I wonder how do I interpret the `[:,0], [:,1],[-10:][::-1]` here?

I stumbled across such notations a lot and I want to get my understanding right. 
I thought it was a simple index at first, but then I realize there is such a thing as `[::-1]` too.
Anybody kindly explain the logic behind them? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Half of those are not Python, per se, they are numpy.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. Numpy has great documentation, and once you're ready for it, check out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html. That page has more than you want to know about expressions just like the ones you are interested in.

Comment: @Stephen. True, but they are bundled by Python into Python objects before being sent to numpy for interpretation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, fair enough, so we can either close as too broad, or close with a dupe of the easier half of the too broad...